# Not getting correct values for string variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code that I have written

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,value):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        self.ext_ip_address = value
    def ip_address_changed(self):
        with open(IP_ADDR, 'r') as ip_address:
            ip_addr = ip_address.read().replace('\n','')
            if not ip_address == self.ext_ip_address:
                self.ext_ip_address = ip_address
                print 'IP ADDR', ip_addr
                print 'EXT IP ADDR', self.ext_ip_address
                return True
        return False



# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
   test_obj = Test('')
   if test_obj.ip_address_changed():
      print "IP changed"
   else:
      print "IP constant"
```

Here I am reading the IP address of a machine from file (i.e. `ip_addr` local variable), then I am checking whether the IP address of machine is changed from the last value (i.e. `self.ext_ip_address`). Then I am trying to print the values of both variables `ip_addr` and `self.ext_ip_address`. For `ip_addr`, I am getting the proper value. But for `self.ext_ip_address` I am getting strange value as below:

```
IP ADDR 192.168.44.100
EXT IP ADDR <open file '/usr/local/bin/data/ip_address.dat', mode 'r' at 0xb772e230>
```

Please let me know what is the reason for this.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should use `ip_address.read().strip()` in instance of `ip_address.read().replace('\n','')` to avoid trailing whitespaces messing with your values

Comment: @VMRuiz Thanks for the tip, but my comment was not meant as an answer. I was responding to a comment Kuro has posted, but apparently has deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the names!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up `ip_addr` and `ip_address` in two places. `ip_address` is your file, which is what you wound up printing instead of the address you had in mind.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,value):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        self.ext_ip_address = value
    def ip_address_changed(self):
        with open(IP_ADDR, 'r') as ip_address:
            ip_addr = ip_address.read().strip()  # Per VMRuiz's comment
            if not ip_addr == self.ext_ip_address:  # HERE
                self.ext_ip_address = ip_addr  # AND HERE
                print 'IP ADDR', ip_addr
                print 'EXT IP ADDR', self.ext_ip_address
                return True
        return False
```

Clearer variable names will prevent this problem in the future.